# Node.js: Returning inserted row from PostgreSQL v.11 to browser

Tags: node.js, postgresql, post

#### I'm new to using Node.js and PostgreSQL.

I'm creating a post request with insert query. 
How can I return inserted values to browser at the same time?

```
app.post('/car_create', (req, res) => {
    const make = req.body.create_make;
    const model = req.body.create_model;

        client.query(`INSERT INTO cars (make, model) VALUES ($1, $2)`, [make, model], (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                throw error
            }
            res.status(201).send(`Car added with ID: ${results};`);
            console.log(res);
            res.end();
        });
});
```

---

How I can retrieve the data from response ?
Do I need to modify this line somehow?

```
            res.status(201).send(`Car added with ID: ${results};`);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need return the values after you insert them in PostgreSQL. To do so, add a `RETURNING` clause to your query, like so: `INSERT INTO cars (make, model) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING id, make, model`. Add more columns in the `RETURNING` clause if you have and want more.

Then in the callback, the `results` variable should contain information about your query, including what it returned (in the `rows` key). You can send it to the client in many ways, but to return it in a similar way as you currently do , you could do this:

```
const {id, make, model} = result.rows[0]; // rows is an array of rows returned, and since we do a single INSERT we only have one row, with the returned columns from the query
res.status(201).send(`Car added with ID ${id}, make "${make}" and model "${model}".`);
```

If you want to use this data on the frontend it would be easier and more convenient to possibly send the data as JSON, like so: `res.status(201).send(results.rows[0]);`

Comment: When i add ```RETURNING id, make, model``` i have an ERROR.

Comment: What is the error? I assumed you have a column called `id` but you could try without it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Samuel!